# Handle messages in Netty without delimiters and message length

Tags: java, netty, delimiter

Is it possible to use netty without any delimiters and knowledge of message length?
I have the following ByteToMessageDecoder implementation:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MessageDecoder extends ByteToMessageDecoder {

    private static final String ENCODING = "ascii";

    @Override
    protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf byteBuf, List out) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

        if (!byteBuf.isReadable()) {
            return;
        }
        byte[] bytes = new byte[byteBuf.readableBytes()];
        byteBuf.readBytes(bytes);

        String outString = new String(bytes, ENCODING);
        System.out.println(outString);

        out.add(outString);
    }
}
```

The problem is that byteBuf might not contain the whole message at the moment of reading. So the message might be splitted into several ones.
Is there a way to handle it?

Comment: Hi, if my answer was helpful, please accept it :). If you have figured it out yourself, please post your own answer. Happy programming!

Comment: I think you are issue can be solve using `ReplayingDecoder`  [link](https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/codec/ReplayingDecoder.html)

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/handler/codec/ByteToMessageDecoder.html) of the ByteToMessageDecoder class:

> Generally frame detection
> should be handled earlier in the pipeline by adding a
> DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder, FixedLengthFrameDecoder,
> LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder, or LineBasedFrameDecoder.
>
> If a custom frame decoder is required, then one needs to be careful
> when implementing one with ByteToMessageDecoder. Ensure there are
> enough bytes in the buffer for a complete frame by checking
> ByteBuf.readableBytes(). If there are not enough bytes for a complete
> frame, return without modifying the reader index to allow more bytes
> to arrive.

So yes there is a way to handle it, you have to either use one of the frame decoders listed in the first paragraph of the docs (which are subclasses off the ByteToMessageDecoder), or create your own custom decoder. If you create your own custom decoder (which extends the ByteToMessageDecoder), make sure u do not increase the reader index of the buffer before the entire message has arrived.

Now further in the documentation it says:

> To check for complete frames without modifying the reader index, use
> methods like ByteBuf.getInt(int). One MUST use the reader index when
> using methods like ByteBuf.getInt(int). For example calling
> in.getInt(0) is assuming the frame starts at the beginning of the
> buffer, which is not always the case. Use in.getInt(in.readerIndex())
> instead.

Which should provide all the ingredients u need to create your own custom frame decoder.

Comment: Hi,
It is easy to say: "or create your own custom decoder"  As I already told, there is no length or dilimeters. Let’s say, we have the following messages: 
1. Hello world 
2. Good
3. third message
In the buffer it looks like: “Hello worldGoodthird message”. I have no idea how to separate it. Perhaps, the only way to do that is to get data length from transport layer (TCP), but i am not sure this can be done via Netty. 
It seems like I will have to give up with Netty and consider another framework as it requires presence of any application protocol which includes frames 

Comment: @AlexanderSpreys sorry I misunderstood your question. I think you're right in that this is not possible due to IP fragmentation. Maybe you could achieve some time-based solution but that would not be very robust.